# Best Linux filesystem for MySQL with a 100% SELECT workload

Tags: mysql, myisam, ext3

I have a MySQL database that contains millions of rows per table and there are 9 tables in total. The database is fully populated, and all I am doing is reads i.e., there are no INSERTs or UPDATEs. Data is stored in MyISAM tables.

Given this scenario, which linux file system would work best? Currently, I have xfs. But, I read somewhere that xfs has horrible read performance. Is that true? Should I shift the database to an ext3 file system?

Thanks

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I have posted the question there.

Answer (score 1):

What about a RAM disk?

Answer (score 0):

it's not about the FS but it can improve your SELECTs. did you evaluated the [mysql table partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html) ?